# Is this regex implication correct?

Tags: proof-verification, regular-expressions

favorite
Prove or disprove the following implication:

Let R and S be arbitrary regular expressions.

(* - Kleene star)
(U - means union)

If R = S* then S(R +S) = S*(R+S)

So, I have figured much this:

```
If R=S* then:
S(R+S)=L(SR) U L(SS)
=L(SS*) U L(SS)
S*(R+S)=L(S*R) U L(S*S)
=L(S*S*) U L(S*S)
=L(S*) U L(S*S)
```

So, in the end the implication is equivalent right?

Comment: Regex is code, not maths. Unless I'm missing something here.

Comment: on the stack overflow everyone said since it involves mathematical proof it should be on math.stackexchange

Comment: It's unclear what your symbols mean. Please clarify ===, U, and *.

Comment: @Furrane: Formal language theory (including regular languages and formalisms for specifying them) is on topic here.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Alright, you can disregard my previous comment then. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is false. For example, suppose the language of $S$ just accepts the string $\mathtt{1}$. If $R = S^*$, then the language of $R$ consists of 0 or more copies of $\mathtt{1}$.

For the left side of the equation, we know:
$$S(R+S) = S(S^*+S) = S(S^*) = SS^*$$

What strings does $SS^*$ accept? It accepts strings that consist of $\mathtt{1}$ followed by zero or more $\mathtt{1}$s. In other words, the language of $S(R+S)$ consists of nonempty strings of $\mathtt{1}$s.

In contrast, $$S^*(R+S) = S^*(S^*+S) = S^*(S^*) = S^*S^* = S^*$$

What strings does $S^*$ accept? It accepts strings that consist of zero or more $\mathtt{1}$s.

The single difference between $SS^*$ and $S^*$ is that $S^*$ accepts the empty string, whereas $SS^*$ does not. Hence when $R=S^*$, the expressions $S(R+S)$ and $S^*(R+S)$ accept slightly different languages.

---

In manipulating these regular expressions, I'm using the fact that $L+L^* = L^*$ for any language, since $L\subseteq L^*$.